# Update a variable used in an infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm using the GPIO on my Raspberry pi to drive a 4 digit 7 segment display. The display is multiplexed and runs in a `while True:` loop.

I want to be able to prompt the user for a new 4 digit number that updates the display. I have tried using threading but the changed variable isn't recognised by the thread updating the display.

Here is a sample of what I thought would work:

```
number = "0000" #used in drive_display() but can be updated in prompt()

def drive_display():
  while True:
    changeDigit(number[0],Digit1)
    time.Sleep(0.006)
    changeDigit(number[1],Digit2)
    time.Sleep(0.006)
    changeDigit(number[2],Digit3)
    time.Sleep(0.006)
    changeDigit(number[3],Digit4)
    time.Sleep(0.006)

threading.Thread(target=drive_display).start()

def prompt():
  number = input("new 4 digit number: ") 
  prompt()

prompt()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt) in the thread function for it to work:

```
def prompt():
  global number
  number = raw_input("new 4 digit number: ") 
  prompt()
```

From the documentation:

> It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without `global`